# Multiple Queries in different table

Tags: sql

*(Also posted [here](http://eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/13/10365934/mulitple-queries-in-different-table.aspx).)*

So I have two tables, one is `invalid` table and the other is `valid` table.

`valid` table:

```
id
status
date
```

`invalid` table:

```
id
status
date
```

I have to produce a report with this output:

```
date       on-time  late  total  valid  invalid1  invalid2  total  rate
---------  -------  ----  -----  -----  --------  --------  -----  ----
9/10/2011  4        10    14     3      3         3         6
```

- `date`: common fields on the 2 tables, field to group by, how many records on that day has
- `on-time`: count of all the id on the valid table
- `late`: count of all the records(id) on the invalid table
- `total`: total of on-time and late
- `valid`: count of id on the valid table with the "valid" status
- `invalid1`: count of id on the invalid table with "invalid1" status
- `invalid2`: count of id on the invalid table with "invalid2" status
- `total`: total of valid, invalid1, invalid2
- `rate`: average of totals

It's basically multiple queries with different table. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Try to format your post properly, please. I tried but I don't know whether `total` and `total rate` are 2 different columns.

Comment: they're two different columns

Comment: I reformatted your post, in particular the output table, as it looked somewhat confusing. Some bits in it still seem missing or unclear. Please review it and modify as appropriate. (For the future, please do *not* use tabs here, they are often result in a messed-up look.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someting like this?

```
SELECT
    *,
    (result.total + result._total) / 2 AS rate
FROM (
    SELECT
        date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN data.valid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ontime,
        SUM(CASE WHEN data.valid = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS late,
        COUNT(*) AS total,
        SUM(CASE WHEN data.valid = 1 AND data.status = 'valid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS valid,
        SUM(CASE WHEN data.valid = 0 AND data.status = 'invalid1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS invalid1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN data.valid = 0 AND data.status = 'invalid2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS invalid2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN data.status IN ('valid', 'invalid', 'invalid2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _total

    FROM (
        SELECT
            date,
            status,
            valid = 1
        FROM
            Valid
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            date,
            status,
            valid = 0
        FROM
            InValid ) AS data
    GROUP BY
        date) AS result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT date, ontime, late, ontime+late total, valid, invalid1, invalid2, valid+invalid1+invalid2 total
FROM
(SELECT date,
       COUNT(*) late,
       COUNT(IIF(status = 'invalid1', 1, NULL)) invalid1,
       COUNT(IIF(status = 'invalid2', 1, NULL)) invalid2,
FROM invalid
GROUP BY date
) JOIN (
SELECT date,
       COUNT(*) ontime,
       COUNT(IIF(status = 'valud', 1, NULL)) valid,
FROM valid
GROUP BY date
) USING (date)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems that you are holding exactly the same information in 2 tables - I would recommend merging those tables together and add an additional boolean column called `valid` to hold the info related to validity of the record.

The query on your existent DB structure might look something like this:

```
SELECT unioned.* FROM (
   ( SELECT v.date AS date, v.status AS status, v.id AS id, COUNT(id) AS valid, 0 AS invalid1, 0 AS invalid2 FROM valid v GROUP BY v.date)
    UNION
   ( SELECT i1.date AS date, i1.status AS status, i1.id AS id, 0 AS valid, COUNT(i1.id) AS invalid1, 0 AS invalid2 FROM invalid1 i1 GROUP BY i1.date)
   UNION
   ( SELECT i2.date AS date, i2.status AS status, i2.id AS id, 0 AS valid, 0 AS invalid1, COUNT(i.id) AS invalid2 FROM invalid1 i1 GROUP BY i1.date)

) AS unioned GROUP BY unioned.date
```

Comment: it gives me the ff error: Column 'unioned.valid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Column 'unioned.invalid1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Column 'unioned.invalid2' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.